# iOS / Cordova app splash screen shifting after load

Tags: ios, cordova

I am having some difficulty with Cordova 2.2.0.

I currently have AutoHideSplashScreen set to "NO". After the app loading is complete, the splash screen shifts up 10px until I run *navigator.splashscreen.hide();* to actually get rid of the splash screen. After it shifts up 10px, the app contents are visible in that 10px space that is left.

Because this only happens after the app has loaded, when I set AutoHideSplashScreen to "YES", the 10px shift doesn't happen. However, I need to be able to hide the splash screen myself.

This only happens on 3.5" iOS devices. On 4" devices the splash screen behaves normally.

Any recommendations? It would seem to me that the problem has to do with *self.imageView.center* in *CDVViewController.m*, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by updating CDVViewController.m:

Previous:

```
Line 695: } else { // not iPad
Line 696:     orientedLaunchImageFile = launchImageFile;
Line 697: }
```

New:

```
Line 695: } else { // not iPad
Line 696:     orientedLaunchImageFile = launchImageFile;
Line 697:     center.y += MIN(statusBarFrame.size.width, statusBarFrame.size.height) / 2;
Line 698: }
```

Comment: I am not able to find this line in my CDVViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

add 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to the project .plist file and set to 'NO'

This stopped the splash screen from moving up before hide() for me.